# VSCode will copy full line when only a word is selected (single click)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm on OSX and running Version 1.42.0 of Visual Studio Code. I have noticed that when I single click a word it will highlight. But if I copy <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and then paste <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, the full line will be in the clipboard. This causes problems from time to time, when the screen has given me every indication that I have only selected a single word. Is there some setting that I can set that will make the default behavior to select a word on a single quote and never *ghost* select a full line?

What it looks like when I single click a word:
[image]

And what it looks like after I've copied and pasted:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[After filing an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90476), it turns out that this behavior is by design.

- The word the cursor is on (from a single click) is highlighted along with every occurrence of that word. The word is not selected (that would be a deeper blue).
- By default copying without a selection copies the current line.

This in my opinion is an Accessibility issue, as there are strong visual clues that a word is selected. I have found that the behavior can be made more intuitive if you set these to settings.

```json
// Controls whether copying without a selection copies the current line.
"editor.emptySelectionClipboard": false,
// Controls whether the editor should highlight semantic symbol occurrences.
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false
```

With these two settings the word the cursor is on will not be highlighted (nor any other occurrences of that word). And if you do happen to copy, with an empty selection, the editor will behave similar to how other applications behave and not copy the current line.